# PHP Includes are chopping when viewing "localhost" on Virtual Machine

Tags: php, macos, virtual-machine, vmware

Here is my setup:  I am coding on a Mac with VMware Fusion loaded (running Windows 8 on the VM).  The VM has IIS running on it so that I can do local testing of my code (written in Edge Code/Brackets).  I test the code by pointing my Mac browser at [ip address]:[port]/[file].  This works fine usually, but I am running into a problem with my includes.

Here is the structure:
[index.php]

```
<body>
<?php require '/Library/Includes/header.inc.php'; ?>

hello
```

[header.inc.php]

```
<div class="container_16">
<div class="grid_6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/298x48" alt="Logo" />
</div>
<div class="grid_10">
    <?php include 'eyebrow.inc.php'; ?>
</div>
```

[eyebrow.inc.php]

```
<ul id="eyebrow-links" class="h-list">
     <li><img src="http://placehold.it/24x24" alt="User Avatar" /></li>
     <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the output when I view the source from my Mac

```
<body>
    <div class="container_16">
    <div class="grid_6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/298x48" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid_10">
        <ul id    </div>
</div>    
hello
```

It's chopping out a bit of my include.  When I test this same code on my Windows Machine, it behaves normally and returns the entire include.  Has anyone else run into this problem?  Any idea what is happening?  I appreciate your help!

Jason

Comment: What happens if you just put `include "/Library/Includes/eyebrow.inc.php";` in `index.php` in place of `header.inc.php`?

Comment: @Barmar:  The eyebrow include functions normally if I do that.  Again, on a separate machine (localhost on my windows laptop, testing locally), it functions normally the way I had originally structured it.  I'm starting to wonder if it is a VM issue or if IIS is setup wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Closing the question.  I think there might have been some kind of conflict between my mac and vm.  Everything is working normally now.  Wish I knew what happened.  @Barmar, thanks for taking the time to start the help process!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be stemming from my first li element.  It might be the reference to placehold.it that is breaking the include.  Not sure why it only seems to have problems on my Mac and not my PC, but at least I'm narrowing down the issue.

UPDATE

Nevermind.  It just continues to break if I have 4 li elements.  Abandoning the issue and just ignoring it.  Sorry!